# TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) Unknown attribute 'shape' of type float32

Tags: python, cuda, jit, numba

I am learning to use numba to accelerate codes in Python. With this code:

```
from numba import cuda, vectorize
import numpy as np

@cuda.jit(device = True)
def pixel_count(img1,img2):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    for i in range(img1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img1.shape[1]):
            if img1[i][j] > 200:
                count1 = count1 + 1
    i = 0; j = 0;
    for i in range(img2.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img2.shape[1]):
            if img2[i][j] > 200:
                count2 = count2 + 1
                         
    return count1, count2


@vectorize(['float32(float32,float32)'], target = 'cuda')
def cint(img1, img2):
    c1, c2 = pixel_count(img1, img2)
    res = c1-c2
    return res

A = np.random.rand(480, 640).astype(np.float32)*255
B = np.random.rand(480, 640).astype(np.float32)*255


res = cint(A,B)
```

I received the following error:

> TypingError: No implementation of function
> Function(<numba.cuda.compiler.DeviceFunctionTemplate object at
> 0x00000175A5BE8C70>) found for signature:   pixel_count (float32, float32)   There are 2 candidate implementations:
> - Of which 2 did not match due to:
> Overload in function 'pixel_count ': File: ..........\OneDrive\Desktop<ipython-input-33-9169f440975d>: Line
> 4.
> With argument(s): '(float32, float32)':
> Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
> TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
> Unknown attribute 'shape' of type float32
>
> ```
>  File "<ipython-input-33-9169f440975d>", line 8:
>  def pixel_count(img1,img2):
>      <source elided>
>      count2 = 0
>      for i in range(img1.shape[0]):
>      ^
>  
>  During: typing of get attribute at <ipython-input-33-9169f440975d> (8)
>  
>  File "<ipython-input-33-9169f440975d>", line 8:
>  def pixel_count(img1,img2):
>      <source elided>
>      count2 = 0
>      for i in range(img1.shape[0]):
>      ^
> ```
>
> raised from
> C:\Users\giuli\anaconda3\envs\GPUcomp\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typeinfer.py:1071
>
> During: resolving callee type:
> Function(<numba.cuda.compiler.DeviceFunctionTemplate object at
> 0x00000175A5BE8C70>) During: typing of call at
>  (3)

*EDIT*

I changed the code like this using guvectorize:

```
@guvectorize(['(float32[:],float32[:], float32)'], '(), () -> ()',target = 'cuda')
def cint(img1, img2, res):
    c1, c2 = pixel_count(img1, img2)
    res = c1-c2


A = np.random.rand(480, 640).astype(np.float32)*255
B = np.random.rand(480, 640).astype(np.float32)*255


res = cint(A, B)
```

With this error:

> TypingError: No implementation of function
> Function(<numba.cuda.compiler.DeviceFunctionTemplate object at
> 0x000001C99C5D42E0>) found for signature:   pixel_count (array(float32, 1d, A), array(float32, 1d, A))   There are 2
> candidate implementations:
>
> - Of which 1 did not match due to:   Overload in function 'pixel_count ': File:
>   ..........\OneDrive\Desktop<ipython-input-33-5b0a51c1200a>: Line
>
> 4. With argument(s): '(array(float32, 1d, A), array(float32, 1d, A))':    Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
>    TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)    Internal error at
>    <numba.core.typeinfer.StaticGetItemConstraint object at
>    0x000001C99DD239D0>.    tuple index out of range    During: typing of
>    static-get-item at  (9)    Enable
>    logging at debug level for details.
>    File "", line 9:    def pixel_count(img1,img2):
>
>    for i in range(img1.shape[0]):
>    for j in range(img1.shape[1]):
>    ^
>
> raised from
> C:\Users\giuli\anaconda3\envs\GPUcomp\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typeinfer.py:1071
>
> - Of which 1 did not match due to:   Overload in function 'pixel_count ': File:
>   ..........\OneDrive\Desktop<ipython-input-33-5b0a51c1200a>: Line
>
> 4. With argument(s): '(array(float32, 1d, A), array(float32, 1d, A))':    Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
>    TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)    Internal error at
>    <numba.core.typeinfer.StaticGetItemConstraint object at
>    0x000001C99DD52370>.    tuple index out of range    During: typing of
>    static-get-item at  (9)    Enable
>    logging at debug level for details.
>    File "", line 9:    def pixel_count(img1,img2):
>
>    for i in range(img1.shape[0]):
>    for j in range(img1.shape[1]):
>    ^
>
> raised from
> C:\Users\giuli\anaconda3\envs\GPUcomp\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typeinfer.py:1071
>
> During: resolving callee type:
> Function(<numba.cuda.compiler.DeviceFunctionTemplate object at
> 0x000001C99C5D42E0>) During: typing of call at
>  (23)

How i can use cuda.jit and vectorize/guvectorize function?

EDIT 2

Thank you all for the responses. The goal was to figure out how to solve this task with GPU using numba. Probably the code is faster in CPU being the matrices small size; thank you for the tips on parallel computing very helpful. Do you have any other suggestions on how to port this code to GPU? Thank you very much.

I have modified the code in this way but it always returns the value 0:

```
from numba import cuda, vectorize, guvectorize
import numpy as np


@cuda.jit(device = True)
def pixel_count(img1,img2):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    for i in range(img1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img1.shape[1]):
            if img1[i][j] > 200:
                count1 = count1 + 1
    i = 0; j = 0;
    for i in range(img2.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img2.shape[1]):
            if img2[i][j] > 200:
                count2 = count2 + 1
                         
    return count1, count2

@guvectorize(['(float32[:,:],float32[:,:], int16)'],
             '(n,m), (n,m)-> ()', target = 'cuda')
def cint(img1, img2, res):
    count1, count2 = pixel_count(img1, img2)
    res = count1 - count2

A = np.random.rand(480, 640).astype(np.float32)*255
B = np.random.rand(480, 640).astype(np.float32)*255
res1 = cint(A, B)
```

Comment: Obviously calling a function which expects an array as an input is not going to work for vectorize, where the functions work on scalars.

Comment: Again, your new version has two dimensional indexing in the device function, but the `guvectorize` specifies one dimensional arrays. In both cases the compiler is literally telling you what the problem is, if you take the time to study the error messages

Comment: Remember, there is no duck typing here. Everything must be explicitly typed and dimensioned and match. The compiler is statically typing everything.

Comment: Do you really want to go through this hassle for something that can be solved with `(A > 200).sum() - (B > 200).sum()`. That expression is already vectorized. If you wish to rely on CUDA, you may wish to decorate that expression with Numba or to explore [CuPy](https://cupy.dev/).

Answer (score 1):

Not using CUDA, but this may give you some ideas:

Pure Numpy (already vectorized):

```
A = np.random.rand(480, 640).astype(np.float32) * 255
B = np.random.rand(480, 640).astype(np.float32) * 255

%timeit (A > 200).sum() - (B > 200).sum()
478 µs ± 4.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Simply wrapping the numpy operations in a JITted function:

```
@nb.njit
def pixel_count_jit(img):
    return (img > 200).sum()

%timeit pixel_count_jit(A) - pixel_count_jit(B)
165 µs ± 13.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Parallelizing with Numba by rows:

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def pixel_count_parallel(img):
    counts = np.empty(img.shape[1], dtype=nb.uint32)
    for i in nb.prange(img.shape[0]):
        counts[i] = (img[i] > 200).sum()
    return counts.sum()

%timeit pixel_count_parallel(A) - pixel_count_parallel(B)
28.5 µs ± 571 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```